# Effects in cube of chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, cube

Good morning, I tried to find information to give some effects to my little cube of rubik, but I could not find any documentation regarding this.

How can I separate the cubes so there is space between them and the rubik cube is larger? and how can I change the texture of its flat color to crystal color?.

The properties I have used are:

```
    var cube = new ERNO.Cube();
    document.body.appendChild( cube.domElement );
    setTimeout(function () {
        cube.twist('UDLF');
        cube.shuffle(50);
    },2500);
    cube.autoRotate = true;
    console.log(cube);
    cube.setSize(500,300);
```

I attach an example of the official page https://www.chrome.com/cubelab

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Look for setRadius(), this will increase radius so you could have an explode-implode effect on the cube, single cubelet, a side, or group etc.

For the following, we include all 27 cublets (even the middle one) but then we only explode-implode outer 26 cublets so that 1 in center of cube stays still.

```
        function(){

            var excluded = new ERNO.Group( cube.cubelets ),
            included = cube.hasColors( window.R, window.Y, window.B )

            excluded.remove( included )
            excluded.setRadius()
            excluded.setOpacity( 0.5 )
            included.setRadius( 120 )
            included.setOpacity( 1 )
            cube.taskQueue.isReady = false
            setTimeout( () => { cube.taskQueue.isReady = true }, 6000 )
        },
        function(){

            cube.setRadius()
            cube.taskQueue.isReady = false
            setTimeout( () => { cube.taskQueue.isReady = true }, 3000 )
        }
```